# Spring AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.scan() is scanning wrong package

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0, spring-annotations

A class of mine (`MyClass.java`) in a certain package (`packageC`) uses an annotation which result in the following error:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.foo.SomeAnnotation] is defined
```

The annotations used are from a 3rd party library (`com.foo`)

I am not using XML to configure Spring. What I do is that during the set up of my application I create an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` object which I use to scan packages for annotated classes and later create beans from that classes.

Application initialiser:

```
...

final private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

public void initApp() {
    //packageC is not scanned
    ctx.scan("packageA", "packageB");
    ctx.refresh();
}

// Called by the application when a bean is required
public <A> A getBeanForClass(Class<A> clazz) {
    return ctx.getBean(clazz);
}

...
```

Since I know that the annotations from the 3rd party library cannot be managed by Spring (rather, Spring cannot create beans from that library) I have excluded from the scan the package of mine which containing classes use the 3rd party annotations:

packageC.MyClass

```
package packageC

import com.foo.Annotation

public class MyClass {

     ...

     @Annotation
     public void someMethod() {
          ...
     }
}
```

My question is why I get the error if I am not telling Spring to create beans from annotated classes in "packageC"???

I have to add that `someMethod()` uses an object from a class in a package which is scanned.

I was probably too vague but I would like to focus on the `scan` behaviour of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` rather than trying to start a discussion about implementation details.

In any case here are some details of my application:

1. The application uses Play! framework (v2.3.8)
2. Spring initialisation is done in the `Global` object (as per [Play-Spring-Jpa](https://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-spring-data-jpa) tutorial)
3. The 'offending' 3rd library is `Deadbolt` (with its `@Restrict` annotations)

Thank you for any clarification you might give me :)

EDIT:

I have found a related problem on [play-framework google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/L9ykn-ypsFM/3ZSbIjb9Q3oJ). Please note that there the guy is actually scanning the package with the annotated classes... I am NOT.

Comment: Did you find the solution yet?

Comment: @biniam_Ethiopia No :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an annotation such as `@Component` or`@Configuration` or `@Service`

at the head of `[com.foo.SomeAnnotation]` class, to make the spring context know it.

is a spring bean.